# Like button state not saved

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift 3 I get data from api by json and check if post is liked or not in my custom cell:

```
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Feedcell", for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell

    //getting the hero for the specified position
    let hero: List_Feed
    hero = heroes[indexPath.row]

    if(hero.mylike=="liked"){
        cell.btnLike.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: .normal)
        cell.btnLike.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleDislikes(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }else{
        cell.btnLike.setImage(UIImage(named: "unliked"), for: .normal)
        cell.btnLike.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleLikes(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

Here is handleDislikes and handleLikes functions:

```
    func handleLikes(sender: AnyObject) {
    let likeid = sender.tag / 100
    let row = sender.tag % 100
    print(likeid)
    print(row)

    let m1 = sender.titleLabel??.text
    let m2 = Int(m1!)
    let m3 = m2!+1
    let m4 = String(m3)

    sender.setTitle(m4, for: .normal)
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: .normal)
    sender.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
    sender.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleDislikes(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func handleDislikes(sender: AnyObject) {
    let likeid = sender.tag / 100
    let row = sender.tag % 100
    print(likeid)
    print(row)

    let m1 = sender.titleLabel??.text
    let m2 = Int(m1!)
    let m3 = m2!-1
    let m4 = String(m3)

    sender.setTitle(m4, for: .normal)
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "unliked"), for: .normal)
    sender.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
    sender.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleLikes(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

So when I tap on like button it "likes it" and button's value becomes value+1. Then, when I scroll down, and scroll up again to this liked post (custom cell), it shows that **button is not pressed**. Why so, my friends?

Comment: Your `handleLikes` and `handleDislikes` methods don't do anything useful. They need to update the data in your `heroes` array.

Comment: @mr-jo : Your handleLikes and handleDislikes only reflect the changes temporarily in order to persist the changes you should modify the corresponding hero object's myLike property

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for your reply! Now I know what to do. Please write your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing comes from how iOS handles cells. To avoid deallocating and reallocating memory when cells scroll out of view and others scroll in iOS reuses the instances of `UITableViewCell`s that goes out of bounds; so you can't rely on the fact that a cell will hold some data because when the same cell will be displayed again it will probably be displayed with a different instance of `UITableViewCell`.

As @rmaddy pointed out in the comment you must save the number of likes inside the `heroes` variable so it can be correctly displayed the next time `tableView(_,cellForRowAtIndexPath:_)` is called.